# How to map elements of an array one below the other instead of side by side in React

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I have an array called `formulas`, which I'm trying to map. However, all elements including a button which is rendered after the map is complete, are appearing side by side instead of one below the other:

Mapping code:

```
     <div style={{ width: "67%" }}>
    {showFormulas && (
                  <WidgetContainer
                    maxHeight={"40vw"}
                    style={{
                      width: "80vw",
                      display: "flex",
                      alignItems: "center",
                      justifyContent: "center",
                    }}
                  >
                {formulas.map((form, index) => {
                  return (
                    <div>
                      <div
                        style={{
                          border: "2px",
                          borderStyle: "solid",
                        }}
                      >
                        hi //gets rendered side by side
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  );
                })}
    
                <button onClick={() => this.addFormula()}> Create New Formula</button> //omitted style for reducing code
              </WidgetContainer>
            )}
</div>
```

this is what the `WidgetContainer` looks like in styles.js

```
export const WidgetContainer = styled.div`
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 24px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
`;
```

How can I render them one below the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are specifying the `display` to `flex`, that's why you are getting them side by side. You either remove the display `flex` or set the `flex-direction` to `column`.